# Vue Multi-Page-Application not working in production

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am trying to implement a MPA with Vue.js and the `pages` configuration option it offers. Like so:
[image]
[image]

This works perfectly when I run my dev server with `npm run serve` and then try to go to `localhost:8080/home` and `localhost:8080/about`. When I try to build this for production with `npm run build` and I try to go to their respective URL's it does not work and only serves me back the index. This seems officially supported by the [Vue Documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) but I can't figure out why this isn't working?

My `dist` folder looks something like this

[image]

Does anybody know what's going on here that's more knowledgeable in Vue.js?

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I did not since I switch to using SPA. I will say though I was hosting this on an S3 bucket served with Cloudfront. I think the only thing I might have had to do is set a custom error to redirect to “index.html” to get the routing to work.